# Why client/server mechanism (using socket's) doesn't work?

Tags: python, c++, sockets, web, client-server

I have free account on www.pythonanywhere.com. I have a server written on c++

```
some_space::socket_server::socket_server(unsigned int port):
     m_port(port),
     m_tcp_fd(0),
     m_udp_fd(0),
     m_newfd(0)
 {
     m_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
     m_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
     m_addr.sin_port = htons(m_port);
 }

 void some_space::socket_server::set_port(unsigned int port)
 {
     assert(port != 0);
     m_port = port;
 }

 int some_space::socket_server::create_tcp_connection()
 {
         m_tcp_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
         if(m_tcp_fd < 0) {
             perror("Error: Cannot set up the communication");
             return -1; 
         }   
         int status = bind(m_tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&m_addr, sizeof(m_addr));       if(status < 0) {
             perror("Error: Cannot set up the communication");
             return -1;
         }
         status = listen(m_tcp_fd, 5);
         if(status == 0) {
             m_newfd = accept(m_tcp_fd, (struct sockaddr*)NULL, NULL);// ####################### The code freezes here (on the accept)
             if(m_newfd != -1) {
                 return m_newfd;
             }
             perror("Error: Cannot accept the connection");
             return -1;
         }
         perror("Error: The port cannot be listened");
         return -1;
     }
```

Where `m_port = 9999`
This cod is runed on .pythonanywhere.com server terminal.

And in the main.

```
    some_space::socket_server* s = new some_space::socket_server(9999);
     assert(s != 0);
     int r = s->create_tcp_connection(); // it it freezes in this function
     assert(r != -1);
     std::string rsp("");
     s->recv_response(rsp);
     std::string rec("some data");
     const char* t = rec.c_str();
     char* buf = const_cast<char*>(t);
     int size = rec.length();
     r = s->send_data(buf, size);
     assert(r != -1);*/
.......................
```

Also, I have a client program in my local pc written on python.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

 import socket

 sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)     
 sock.connect(('<username>.pythonanywhere.com', 9999))
 sock.send('hello, world!')     
 data = sock.recv(1024)     
 print "receive >>> %s" % data     
 sock.close()
```

But the problem is the client can't connect with the server, it waits always. Where is a problem?

Comment: What did your debugging and checking returns from system calls tell you?

Comment: In all places, I have the "asserts", so the problem is not in the incorrect return values

Comment: So, if your server does not even respond to the client's connection attempt, it is likely that the attempt did not get through. That is, your problem is "in the network setup". Check the firewall settings of client as well as server. Check with other tools such as `nmap` that your server is actually reachable from the outside. Check with other servers if your client request goes through the network. These are the first steps for you to narrow down the issue.

Comment: Jan-Philip Gehrcke - Thank you for productive comment. A few minute ago, I have read, that www.pythonanywhere.com have not open ports. And there is also nmap log, according that "No support for 'AF_INET (tcp) on this system" .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PythonAnywhere dev here: PythonAnywhere only supports web apps using the Python WSGI protocol, which covers almost all of the main Python web frameworks (Django, web2py, Flask, Bottle, etc) but won't work with your own C-based server.