# Django via TCP socket

Tags: python, django, sockets, tcp

I have created django app that I uploaded on "pythonanywhere website".
This app use quite a big database which I have to update every day and I wanted this database to be on my computer only.
Inside on of my django view I have created TCP client and after user type some information to app, this client send query to database on address when my server with database is running (my computer IP).
Everything was good on local network. I could connect to database from one computer to another and receive answer from it. Unfortunatelly I am unable to do it online on "pythonanywhere" website. I have read that it's impossible to do it through this website right now and I am looking for some alternative way to solve this problem.

Long story short. I am looking for a way to deploy my django website and connect it with server on my computer.
If there is some other, easier way to do it, please advise, but I would rather keep my database on computer.

Thank you.

Comment: This is quite the undertaking. You will have to deal with forwarding ports from your local network to the internet and handle the security implications of doing so. I also expect your upload speed is pretty slow which will impact the performance of the application. You will also need a domain name with either a static IP from your ISP or a way to update the IP when it changes. I would suggest you start by researching how to safely forward ports to the internet and see if you really want to deal with that.

Comment: I have finished with port forwarding already. Everything is good and set up. Server is listening on port and receive data from websites. The problem is that I cannot use "pythonanywhere" site to host my django app and use it that way. This website simply not work that way. That's why I am looking for other way.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question. It appears the free plan for pythonanywhere only lets you connect to certain websites, are you on the free plan? It should work otherwise.

Comment: Yes I am on free account. Here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28528086/why-client-server-mechanism-using-sockets-doesnt-work you can see that this website don't work with TCP clients from what I understand.

Comment: PythonAnywhere developer here -- FamousJameous is entirely correct, free PythonAnywhere accounts can't make TCP connections to the outside Internet.  Paid accounts can, so if you've got the port forwarding set up correctly, you should be fine if you upgrade to a paid account.